# How to reference a different mscorlib.dll from within VS2015?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I'm contributing to [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) and I'm building my own copy of mscorlib. I'm trying to test my changes via creating a new *Console Application* in VS and referencing that copy of mscorlib instead of the built-in one, but it doesn't seem to be working.

So far, I've added this line to my project's properties (by editing the `.csproj` file manually):

```
<NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
```

However, when I reload the project and go to *References > Add Reference* and select the custom-built mscorlib, I get this dialog box:

[image]

How do I fix this? Would I have to manually edit the `.csproj` file again, or is there some property I'm missing that would fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up adding this to the `.csproj` file manually:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="mscorlib">
    <!-- Replace with whatever your path to mscorlib is -->
    <HintPath>$(UserProfile)\Code\git\coreclr\bin\Product\Windows_NT.x64.Release\mscorlib.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

After that everything worked as expected.